# slack: Delete all messages with php

Tags: php, slack, slack-api

I'm trying to delete all message of a slack channel

i tried to add the required scopes to the app but this two scopes aren't available

chat:write:user

chat:write:bot

i tried with the bot and the user token after reinstall the workspace

the function getAllMessagesFromChannel() i wrote works and i get all the timestamps correctly

```
    public function clearChannel()
    {
        $jsonData = $this->getAllMessagesFromChannel();

        foreach ($jsonData->messages as $message) {
            $this->deleteMessage($message->ts);
        }
    }

    private function deleteMessage($ts)
    {

        $data = json_encode(array("channel" => $this->channel, "ts" => $ts));
        $ch = curl_init("https://slack.com/api/chat.delete");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8', "Authorization: Bearer " . $this->token));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        echo $result . "\n";
        curl_close($ch);
    }
```

i get this error for every message:

```
{"ok":false,"error":"cant_delete_message"}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRpEz.png)

any idea how to fix this?

Comment: they disabled deleting bulk messages unless you have a premium account

Comment: wasted my day on this. so big thanks to you

Comment: did the same a few years back... just automate it with selenium and python... via the browser website, way easier... however they do have api limiting, so just play with this idea till you have your messages deleted. also you're welcomed! <3